# Bootstrap Carousel not switching through images

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to make a carousel of 2 images and I have all the components- arrows, indicator, first image, but when I click the arrows, nothing happens.

I have absolutely no idea what to do as I was just following a tutorial and everything looks all right.

```html
<div id="run-images" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="run-images" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="run-images" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="Greens%20View.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="clarks.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#run-images" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#run-images" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

I want the carousel to cycle through the images but when the arrow is clicked, nothing happens. Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling bootstrap js and css correctly?

Comment: Pretty sure. I used w3schools tutorial so I'm pretty sure I called everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carousel-fade` was added in Bootstrap version 4.0 or higher.

Make sure to have the newest files included and the bootstrap js and css match the version number.

Edit: Your code is totally correct. I tried a jsfiddle and used version 4.1.3 of Bootstrap and it worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with this class. `carousel-fade` just add a fade transition to the carousel.

Comment: I tried it, after removing that class the slider worked for me. Using Bootstrap version 4.

Comment: Didn't work. The buttons are the things that don't work. When I press them, nothing happens.

Comment: @otc09 As I said, it has nothing to do with this class. What you are describing seems like a JavaScript problem. Have you called Bootstrap.js on your html correctly?

Comment: I think so. I used bootstrap's CDN and put it at the top of the head

Comment: But have you called jQuery and Bootstrap.js before closing `<body>` tag?

Comment: Okay check your Bootstrap version. Might be a problem with versions of the css and js. They have to match. `carousel-fade` comes with version 4 or higher

Comment: See the jsfiddle. Its your code. Just embeded the right bootstrap version top. https://jsfiddle.net/bvmrf35n/1/

Comment: @davidev after several updates, you answered the same thing as I did in the first place. There is no need to do that.

Comment: @davidev and it is not necessary to  import popper in this case. It should work only with jQuery and Bootstrap.

Comment: @LucasArbex Yes you are right, my mistake. I just wanted to point out to have Bootstrap version 4.1.3

Comment: @davidev It happens, but avoid doing that in the future. :)

Comment: @LucasArbex Thanks, I am gladly taking any advices

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything is fine, but don't forget to add jQuery and Bootstrap.js to your code before closing `<body>` tag, and also check if the Bootstrap version of the tutorial is exact the same as the one you are using.

For further information, please [check this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).